# Possible to set a user role with a guild id and a role name

Tags: c#, discord.net

I want to add roles to users on my discord from my API, withc sends a JSON string with their tag/id and the roles.

`{"errros":[],"success":"true","data":[{"id":"264393690045218816","ranks":"developer,verified"},{"id":"265510731363909632","ranks":"developer"}]}`

This responseString runs inside a CheckAccount() task. It is not triggered by a command but a timer, and therefor this did not work, i tried to adabt it to use only guild and role id but can't figure out how it works:

```
var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ROLE NAME");
await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
```

task["id"] = users id/tag.
rank is the rank name.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JToken jData = jObject["data"];
foreach (var task in jData)
{
    string ranks = task["ranks"].ToString();
    foreach (string rank in ranks.Split(','))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task["id"].ToString() + " recieved rank " + rank);
    }
}
```

In the end i want to send a tag/id and role over an API, then every hour it checks and adds the roles.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what isn't working. If your code isn't being run in a command then where does `Context` come from? Also, you don't show how you try to utilize the Id and ranks from the responseString to add a role. That code snippet that does the `Console.WriteLine` isn't really useful in relation to your question either...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Anu6is The `Context` was from all the examples i found on the internet. Thats the problem, i don't know what to write instead of `context`. It was more of a illustration. 

ANd the `Console.Write` was just leftover from testing. Forgot to remove it

Comment: Ok. `Context` is simply a variable provided in command modules to assist with making references in commands a little easier. Anything you can do with `Context` you can do with your `DiscordSocketClient` and `SocketUserMessage` as `Context` is really just a combination of the two. If you have access to your client in the timer, then you can use `yourClientObject.GetGuild(guild_id_here)` to get the guild object, then like with the context example you would have access to `guild.roles`. You can also get the user from the guild with `youGuildObject.GetUser(user_id_here), if you don't have a user

Comment: @Anu6is it took a bit of time to figure it out, but it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to manually specify my guild